# Use shared libraries in /usr/local/lib

Tags: ubuntu, libraries

I have build some libraries from sources, and the files after `make install` are in `/usr/local/lib`

For example, in my case I have the file `libodb-2.2.so` which is in this directory.

However when I launch the executable that has linked with `libodb`, I got the error: error while loading shared libraries: `libodb-2.2.so: cannont open shared object file: No such file or directory.`

Does it mean that I have build my executable not correctly ? or should I indicate the system that there may be some interesting libs in the folder `/usr/local/lib` also ?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, Linux kernel 3.2.0-38-generic.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/165027/why-cant-my-program-find-the-libraries-in-usr-local-lib , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17889799/libraries-in-usr-local-lib-not-found

Comment: I strongly suggest you making good friendship relation with your debugger

Comment: @DDS I suggest that you elaborate a bit more. You know it's a collaborative site here.  Please, indicate the way `gdb` would have helped in anyway with a `link` problem, for example. I am genuinely curious. At first your remark seems to me *unrelated* to the problem. But I may be wrong. Indeed I do not know enough `gdb`, and the loading of libraries.

Comment: Sorry... this comment should have been placed on stackoverflow on a learner's question about C programming... just didn't seen was  U&L

Comment: @DDS Beginner at learning C programming, or at learning building on Linux? Please, be more precise. For example I was coming from Windows. That does not mean I don't know C++... I tend to think your judgmental behaviour is not accurate. Even if it had been on SO, your behaviour will soon get the attention of moderators. Be aware of that. You are on a COLLABORATIVE site, of enthusiast programmers sharing useful knowledge. Not somewhere design to flatter your ego. (Don't worry I have also been gently /reasonably bashed when I started SO, and I think that was a really good thing that happened).

Comment: C programming: he asked why his code were stopping suddently. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54653523/check-that-command-line-input-is-numeric/54653550#comment96098874_54653550

Answer (score 88, accepted):

For the current session you can

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib
```

or to make the change permanent you can add `/usr/local/lib` to `/etc/ld.so.conf` (or something it includes) and run `ldconfig` as root.

If you're still having problems, running `ldd [executable name]` will show you the libraries it's trying to find, and which ones can't be found.

Comment: From the `man` page for `ldd(1)` "In the usual case, ldd invokes the standard dynamic linker (see `ld.so(8)`) with the `LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS` environment variable set to `1`, which causes the linker to display the library dependencies.  Be aware, however, that in some circumstances, some versions of `ldd` may attempt to obtain the dependency information by directly executing the  program. Thus, you should never employ `ldd` on an ***untrusted executable***, since this may result in the execution of arbitrary code.  A safer alternative when dealing with *untrusted* executables is: ..."

Comment: "... `$ objdump -p /path/to/program | grep NEEDED`"

Comment: Nice one -- I've never come across objdump before.

Comment: As per [this](http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/_/ldpath.html) article this answer is canonically **incorrect** and **harmful**. For a correct approach the use of `-L` and `-rpath` during compile to set the linking search path and runtime search path for libraries is the correct way, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25918462/why-ld-library-path-is-bad-and-the-correct-way-to-load-dynamic-libraries) question and answer.

Comment: I see libc.conf have it desired path `/usr/local/lib`, then  `ldconfig` solve it to me.

Comment: What I don't understand is why an executable in `/usr/local/bin` would not be able to locate a library in `/usr/local/lib` without modification to environment variables or configurations. What logical reason is there for this? I mean I can execute it from the terminal without adding `/usr/local/bin` to the path, so why shouldn't it be able to find a library in `/usr/local/lib`?

Answer (score 65):

If you've already run `ldconfig` after building the library, keep reading.  If not, [read aboout ldconfig](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig) first.

`/usr/local/lib` might not be in the library path that ldconfig uses.  You can just do this:

```
ldconfig /usr/local/lib
```

And the stuff should be added to the linker cache, but it is probably better to add the path properly.  Make sure you have a `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` directory.  If so add a file (call it "usr-local.conf", or whatever), and put one line in it:

```
/usr/local/lib
```

Now run `ldconfig`.  If you don't have the ld.so.conf.d directory, you should have a `/etc/ld.so.conf` *file* and you can add that line to the end of it.

Comment: I've added a custom.conf file to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` then sudoed ldconfig to take it into account and my executable can start now.